# Get the value from xpath in selenium

Tags: testing, selenium

How can I get the value from xpath in Selenium.

```
public void DummyFunc(String startDate){
        String test;
        test=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//startDate"));           
    }
```

I am passing the location of the table like table > tr > td but I am getting an error when I use String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer need more precision. If "by value" you mean "text", you can have it with `getText()` method (it return the `innerHTML`):

```
public void DummyFunc(String startDate){
   String test;
   test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//"+startDate));           
   return test.getText()
}
```

edit : 
btw, `table > tr > td` is not a valid xpath string. It should be `//table/tr/td`